# Why exactly would using applicative functors be inferior to monads for integer division?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm reading Graham Hutton's Programming in Haskell and am confused with the flow of thought outlined below.

He uses the example below to motivate the use of monads by showing the shortcomings of applicative functors for a divide operation where the return type is a `Maybe` to handle the error case indicating a potential *division by zero* scenario.

Given:

```
data Expr = Val Int | Div Expr Expr

safediv :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
safediv _ 0 = Nothing
safediv n m = Just (n `div` m)

eval :: Expr -> Maybe Int
eval (Val n) = pure n                               --type: Just(n)?
eval (Div x y) = pure safediv <*> eval x <*> eval y --type: Maybe(Maybe Int)?
```

He goes on to explain:

> However, this definition is not type correct. In particular, the
>   function `safediv` has type `Int->Int->Maybe Int`, whereas in the
>   above context a function of type `Int->Int->Int` is required.
>
> Replacing `pure safediv` by a custom defined function wound not help
>   either, because this function would need to have type
>   `Maybe(Int->Int->Int)`, which does not provide any means to indicate
>   failure when the second integer argument is zero. (X)
>
> The conclusion is that the function `eval` does not fit the pattern of
>   effectful programming that is captured by applicative functors. The
>   applicative style restricts restricts us to applying pure functions to
>   effectful arguments: `eval` does not fit this pattern because the
>   function `safediv` that is used to process the resulting values is not
>   a pure function, but may itself fail.

I'm not a Haskell programmer but from the type of `eval (Div x y)` it seems be that of `Maybe(Maybe Int)` - which can simply be *squashed*, no? (Something like a `flatten` in Scala or `join` in Haskell). What really *is* the issue here?

Irrespective of whether `x,y` are `Just(s)/Nothing(s)` it seems `safediv` will correctly evaluate - the only issue here is the return type which can be transformed appropriately. How exactly does the author go from his argument to this conclusion is what I'm having a hard time understanding.

> ...applicative style restricts restricts us to applying pure functions to effectful arguments

Also, why does paragraph marked `(X)` above make that claim when the problem just seems to be or return type misalignment.

I understand applicatives can be used for more efficiently chaining computations where the results of one don't impact the other - but in this case I'm rather confused as to how/where the failure would happen and if just a simple return type fix would solve the problem:

```
eval (Div x y) = join(pure safediv <*> eval x <*> eval y)
```

And does `safediv` *have to be pure*? AFAIK it could also be of type `F[Maybe]` or `F[Either]`, no? What may I be missing? I can see *where* he's going but not sure if this is the right example to get there IMHO.

Comment: Applicatives don't have the concept of `join`. To get `join` you need a monad. And that's the whole point here: applicatives not enough, you need a monad.

Comment: to put it differently: when your data type has `join` (on top the other stuff from Applicative Functor), it *is* a Monad.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I'm not a Haskell programmer but from the type of `eval (Div x y)` it seems be that of `Maybe(Maybe Int)` - which can simply be *squashed*, no? (Something like a `flatten` in Scala or `join` in Haskell). What really *is* the issue here? … the only issue here is the return type which can be transformed appropriately

This *is* the key issue! ‘Squashing’ is a fundamentally monadic operation — in fact, the type signature of `join` is `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a`. If you restrict yourself to the applicative methods `pure` and `(<*>)`, there is no way to implement this, but it becomes easy if you let yourself use `(>>=)` as well. Sure, you can easily implement `flattenMaybe :: Maybe (Maybe a)) -> Maybe a` without using monads, but that defeats the purpose of concepts like `Applicative` and `Monad`, which should be applicable to a wide range of types, not just `Maybe`.

> Irrespective of whether `x,y` are `Just(s)/Nothing(s)` it seems
>   `safediv` will correctly evaluate - the only issue here is the return
>   type which can be transformed appropriately. How exactly does the
>   author go from his argument to this conclusion is what I'm having a
>   hard time understanding.
>
> > ...applicative style restricts restricts us to applying pure functions to effectful arguments
>
> Also, why does paragraph marked `(X)` above make that claim when the
>   problem just seems to be or return type misalignment.

The idea here is this. Let’s say you have two functions, and two values:

```hs
nonEffectful :: a -> b -> c
effectful    :: a -> b -> m c

effectfulA :: m a
effectfulB :: m b
```

Now, if you want to apply the `nonEffectful` function to the two effectful arguments, `m` only needs to be `Applicative`: it’s easy to do `nonEffectful <$> effectfulA <*> effectfulB :: m c`. But if you try that with the `effectful` function instead, you run into a problem: you get a return type of `m (m c)` instead of `m c`. To ‘squash’ `m (m c)` into `m c`, you need a `Monad` instance. So applicatives can only apply pure (non-effectful) functions to effectful arguments, but monads let us apply effectful functions to effectful arguments. This is what Hutton was attempting to do this, but with a specific function `safeDiv :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int`.

(One thing I didn’t mention in the above discussion is intuition: *why*, on an intuitive rather than formal level, are monads required for specific computations? As you have already noticed, the answer has to do with dependency. For `nonEffectful <$> effectfulA <*> effectfulB`, the two effectful values have no impact on each other. However, with `effectful <$> effectfulA <*> effectfulB`, suddenly there is a dependency: the `effectful` function must depend on the results of the effectful computations passed to it. `Monad` can be thought of as representing the idea of effectful computations which can depend on each other, whereas `Applicative` represents the idea of effectful computations which cannot depend on each other (although a pure function may depend on them). Similarly, in order to evaluate a nested computation `m (m a)`, you first need to evaluate the outer computation, and then evaluate the resulting inner effectful computation. Again we have an effectful computation which depends on another effectful computation, so this requires a `Monad`.)

Comment: Aaah! I see. That makes total sense. Thank you 